# C# WPF how to make different looking DataTemplates based on binded class object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to build a DataTemplate in XAML with a binded List. The problem I have is, that the list contains objects of base class and the derived class.
It would be very nice when based on what object comes next out of the list (base class object or derived class object) the XAML Code could build two different looking DataTemplates.
More precisley, the derived class object has one more property then the base class object and that I want to display with an additional textbox for example. And therefor I would like to have that XAML makes the work on its own looking for what object it is and then build this or that DataTemplate.
Has anyone an idea to do something like that?

Comment: Datatemplating can be based on datatype. And you should be able to find other so questions explain this. Or you could read the msdn documentation. You are expected to search before posting a Question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `DataTemplates` as resources for your `ListView`.

Something like this:

```
<ListView>
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BaseClass}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyOfBaseClass}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DerivedClass}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyOfBaseClass}" />      
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyOfDerivedClass}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```